# Find $E[Y_nY_{n+3}]$ of an AR(2) process

Tags: self-study, stationarity, autoregressive

Consider an AR($2$) Process that is given by

$$Y_n=a_1Y_{n-1} + a_2Y_{n-2} + X_n,$$

where $X_n$ is a zero-mean IID random sequence with Var($X_n$)$~=1$.

We further assume that $Y_n$ is WSS. Find $E[Y_nY_{n+3}]$ if $a_1=1$ and $a_2=-1/4$.

Comment: For a general result of the autocovariance function of an $AR(p)$ process, see Example 3.3.4 of *Time Series: Theory and Methods* by Peter J. Brockwell and Richard A. Davis.

Comment: You should clarify the abbreviation WSS for readers less familiar with the term (presumably you intend *weak-sense stationary* but there's no need to leave readers to guess)

Answer (score 2):

Hint, find the following in order:

1. $E[Y_nY_n]$
2. $E[Y_{n+1}Y_n]$
3. $E[Y_{n+2}Y_n]$
4. $E[Y_{n+3}Y_n]$

Edit: as per request, here's a way to solve (2). At this point, from (1), we know that $E[Y_n^2]  = (1 - a_1^2 - a_2^2)^{-1}.$ Then we use this fact in the next step:
\begin{align*}
E[Y_{n+1}Y_n] &= E[(a_1Y_n + a_2 Y_{n-1} + X_{n+1})Y_n] \tag{defn. of model} \\
&= a_1 E[Y_n^2] + a_2 E[Y_n Y_{n-1}] + 0 \tag{linearity of $E$}\\
&= a_1 E[Y_n^2] + a_2 E[Y_{n+1} Y_{n}]. \tag{stationarity}
\end{align*}
So $E[Y_{n+1}Y_n] = a_1(1 - a_1^2 - a_2^2)^{-1} + a_2E[Y_{n+1} Y_{n}]$. Do a little algebra, then you get $E[Y_{n+1} Y_{n}](1-a_2) = a_1(1 - a_1^2 - a_2^2)^{-1}$, which means $E[Y_{n+1} Y_{n}] = a_1(1 - a_1^2 - a_2^2)^{-1}(1-a_2)^{-1}$.

Comment: i am new in that and i am not know how to find out the perfect way. can you help me in this

Comment: @AnonymousNaz which number are you stuck on

Comment: i mean simply how to calculate 2. part.

Comment: E[Yn+1Yn]? this one

Comment: @AnonymousNaz that equals $E[(a_1Y_n + a_2 Y_{n-1} + X_{n+1})Y_n]$

Comment: can you please solve this question completely.

Comment: I'm only supposed to help you along if it's a `self-study` question. Tell me where you get stuck

Comment: i understand this question little bit but do not know exact path how to start and how to solve in right direction

Comment: @AnonymousNaz $E[(a_1Y_n + a_2 Y_{n-1} + X_{n+1})Y_n] = a_1 E[Y_n^2] + a_2 E[Y_n Y_{n-1}] + 0 = a_1 E[Y_n^2] + a_2 E[Y_{n+1} Y_{n}]$ does that help? Remember you are trying to solve for $E[Y_{n+1}Y_n]$

Comment: thanku so much for your help .....then what will be the next steps and if that is ... then how to solve E[YnYn]

Comment: $E[Y_n^2]$ you have from the previous step. That’s why I suggested you find these cross moments at higher and higher lags—so you can use precious answers to obtain new answers.

Comment: can you please share me the procedure of part-1 solution how to sovlve that

Comment: @AnonymousNaz see my edit above

Comment: can you please tell me how you get the E[Y2n]=(1−a21−a22)−1